# Google chart bar, the colum not showing decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I have this code who select's from my mysql database some marks.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
           title: 'Statisica note',
          is3D: 'true',          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          width: 872,
          height: 300,
          min:0,         vAxis: { gridlines: { count: 9 } },
          max:10
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
```

All is going good but doesent show the numbers as " 1.22, 2.45" on the bar colums. what i have to do?

Image:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I made it.

Instead of:

```
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Nota']);
```

I changed with:

```
$temp[] = array('v' => (float) $r['Nota']);
```